# Call Python from jQuery in Google App Engine platform

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine

UPDATED:
Changed to simpler python script

I have a website hosted in Google App Engine which is mostly static. Now I have a python script that would return a list of files under a specific folder in the server. I need this list of files in JavaScript.

helloworld.py

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2 World!')
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/GetImages', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

I am calling this Python script in a `<script>` tag in my index.html using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/GetImages",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

In my app.yaml I have this handler defined and also other handlers for static files

```
- url: /GetImages
  script: helloworld.app
```

I have started Google App Engine launcher, and when I open my site in localhost:8080/GetImages, I don't see the hello world string.

I think the problem is with my app.yaml. If I add below in the handlers, I get server error. Is this not allowed?

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

Comment: Accessing http://localhost:8080/GetImages with your browser should show you the result of the request.

Comment: @leo That gives me a server error. `HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.`

Comment: If you can't access /GetImages, chances are good your javascript can't either. You'll need to figure out why that URL isn't working and then you can proceed down the line of debugging your JS.

Comment: maybe someone can help me with whatever the problem is with my setup?

Comment: Are you sure it's your setup? Try returning a simple message and see if it works. If it does, then chances are your function is wrong (..\images doesn't exist, for example).
BTW: are you sure ..\images is the way to reference the images folder??? Why BACKSLASH?

Comment: Can you post your `app.yaml`?

Comment: @leo The previous script on images is working from terminal. I have updated the post to use a simpler script. RocketDonkey, I have deduced that the problem is with app.yaml. When I add another handler, I get the server error

Comment: found the problem. Some incorrect indent in the python script. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The problem was some incorrect indent in the python script. Stupid mistake :)